# Extendable menu using CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a menu like the screenshot

1. the red arrow means when I click on the button it will either show /
   hide the menu
2. the orange arrow means when menu is hide the box should increase the
       width, and vice versa

[image]

So far I have created the html, the problem is

1) the sliding effect seems not exactly what I expected, it slide after the content is show , but what I would like to achieve is hide and slide at same time

```
            $("#menu_btn").on("click", function () {
                var menu = $("#left_menu #btn");
                if (menu.css('display') !== "none") {
                    $("#left_menu #btn").hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
                } else {
                    $("#left_menu #btn").show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
                }
            });
```

2) how to combine the code to  extend / decrease width after the slide effect, and the box is absolute in the container , can I keep the same top after the content expend / reduce?

```
$(".content #bg").css("width","600");
$(".content #bg").css("width","1000");
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work: 
https://jsfiddle.net/7k4kdmxu/4/

CSS:

```
.container{width:100%; margin:0 auto;}
nav{
   width:20%;
    float:left;
     background:#efefef; 
}
.openNav{ width:20%;}
#content.openNavContainer{ width:80%!important;}
.closeNav{width:10%;}
#content.closeNavContainer{ width:90%!important;}
#content{
    width:80%;
    float:right;
    background:#e9e9e9; 
}
nav ul {list-style:none;}
nav ul li{list-style:none; display:block;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<nav>
    <a href="#" id="open">Open -></a>
    <ul>

        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">OUT VALUE</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">SEASONAL</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
   </ul>
    <a href="#" id="close"><- Close </a>
</nav>
    <div id="content"><p>Body Content Can Go Here</p></div>
</div>
```

JS/JQ

```
$(function(){
$("#open").click(function(){

    $("nav").addClass("openNav");
     $("nav").removeClass("closeNav");
    $("#content").addClass("openNavContainer");
    $("#content").removeClass("closeNavContainer");
});
$("#close").click(function(){
        $("nav").addClass("closeNav");
      $("nav").removeClass("openNav");
    $("#content").addClass("closeNavContainer");
    $("#content").removeClass("openNavContainer");
    });
});
```